nock is not intercepting HTTPS request to Keyclaok
I have been struggling in the last two days to figure out what is not working well with my nock setup.
Description:

I work with node environment and express as the application server.
The authentication flow is openid-connect using openid-client npm package and passport strategy.
I am working with Keycloak as the Identity Provider- so to access an app, you first
need to authenticate in Keyclaok.In development mode, I want to mock all the outgoing
Keyclaok requests:

https://keycloak-domain.com/realms/Demo-Realm/.well-known/openid-configuration
https://keycloak-domain.com/realms/Demo-Realm/protocol/openid-connect/auth



However, as hard as I try to mock the requests to Keyclaok, the requests always reach the Keycloak server domain and I did not get the mock response set in nock.
When bootstrapping the application, once I set the express server created I run the nock setup (it runs before initializing the openid-client and ant passport strategies).
Below is my nock setup:
export const initializeMiddleware = async () => {
  const keycloakBaseUrl = "https://keycloak-domain.com/realms/Demo-Realm";
  const wellKnownEndpoint = "/.well-known/openid-configuration";
  const tokenEndpoint = "/protocol/openid-connect/token";
  const scope: Scope = nock(keycloakBaseUrl);
    scope
        .persist()
        .get(wellKnownEndpoint)
        .query(true)
        .reply(StatusCodes.OK, {
            issuer: keycloakBaseUrl,
            authorization_endpoint: `${keycloakBaseUrl}${authEndpoint}`,
            token_endpoint: `${keycloakBaseUrl}${tokenEndpoint}`,
            userinfo_endpoint: `${keycloakBaseUrl}${userInfoEndpoint}`,
            jwks_uri: `${keycloakBaseUrl}${jwksUri}`,
        });
    scope
        .persist()
        .get(tokenEndpoint)
        .query(true)
        .reply(StatusCodes.OK, { user: { email: 'gavri1411@gmail.com' } });
}

Thanks in advance to anyone who can assist me with this one.
